# Filtrar un campo de una tabla dinamica según un intervalo VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

tengo una duda al filtrar una tabla dinamica en VBA, lo que quiero hacer es filtrar un campo de acuerdo a un intervalo especifico

[image]

Por ejemplo, filtrar el campo centro de beneficio para que solo aparezcan del 3205000 al 3205003

Si le doy en la opción grabar macro Excel me da la siguiente opción de código que funciona, pero quiero aplicarlo en varios archivos por lo tanto no se puede de esta manera

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica1").PivotFields( _
        "Centro de beneficio")
        .PivotItems("3205004").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205018").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205019").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205020").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205021").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205022").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205023").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205024").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205029").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3205030").Visible = False
    End With
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 4):

para aplicar un filtro de ese estilo lo mejor es iterar por los PivotItem de la tabla. Algo parecido a esto:

```
For Each pvtItm In PTable.PivotFields("Tarea").PivotItems

    If pvtItm.Caption = "480" Or pvtItm.Caption = "4820" Then
        pvtItm.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtItm.Visible = False
    End If

Next
```

En tu caso sería acotar el rango y comprobar si es mayor que el valor inicial del filtro y menor que el valor final. En tu caso cambia el .Caption por .Value:

```
For Each pvtItm In PTable.PivotFields("Centro de beneficio").PivotItems

    If pvtItm.Value >= 3205000  Or pvtItm.Value <= 3205003 Then
        pvtItm.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtItm.Visible = False
    End If

Next
```

Lo que esto hace es comprobar uno a uno los campos que le indiques y si está dentro de tu filtro lo deja como Visible y en caso contrario lo oculta.

Te pongo un ejemplo para montar una tabla dinámica con código. Sin ver tus datos es complicado adaptarla a lo que necesitas:

```
Sub tabla()

    'Variables y objetos de la tabla
    Dim PCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim pvtFld As PivotField
    Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
    Dim sht_tdt As Worksheet

   'Nombre de la hoja donde irá la tabla
   Set sht_tdt = Thisworkbook.Sheets("MiHoja")

   'Rango de datos de la tabla
   Set PRange = Thisworkbook.Sheets("HojaDatos").Range("A1:J50")



   'Creamos la tabla
   Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sht_tdt.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="TD_Datos")

    'Definimos la tabla
    Set PTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos")

  sht_tdt.Activate

    'Campos de filas. Aquí modifica los campos (PivotFields) con los que tienes tu
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos").PivotFields("Matricula")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos").PivotFields("Nombre")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
        '.Name = "Matrícula"
    End With

    'Campos de columnas. Lo mismo que en los campos de filas. Cambialos por los tuyos
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos").PivotFields("Fecha")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    'Campos de datos. Aquí añades los datos que quieres mostrar

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos").PivotFields("Pics/Hora")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlSum
        .Name = "Pic/Hora"
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TD_Datos").PivotFields("% err")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 2
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Name = "% de Err."
    End With

    'Filtro para tu Campo Centro de beneficio
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(nombretabla).PivotFields("Centro de beneficio")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

   'Por último ocultas/muestras lo valores que quieras

   For Each pvtItm In PTable.PivotFields("Centro de beneficio").PivotItems

    If pvtItm.Value >= 3205000  Or pvtItm.Value <= 3205003 Then
        pvtItm.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtItm.Visible = False
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Adapta el código a tus datos y prueba. Si tienes problemas intenta poner por aquí una muestra de los datos y tú código. O cuelga el fichero en algún lado para poder echarle un ojo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, todavía soy un poco nuevo en el uso de VBA, cuando pego el código así no más no me aparece ninguna macro y si le pongo el Sub al inicio y luego End Sub me arroja un error 424 diciendo que se requiere un objeto y cuando le doy en depurar me subraya esta linea de código `For Each pvtItm In PTable.PivotFields("Centro de beneficio").PivotItems `

Comment: Claro, eso es porque antes tienes que definir los objetos y variables. Todo va dentro del Sub. Voy a ampliar mi respuesta.